# How to elegantly symbolize_keys for a 'nested' hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, dry

Consider the following code:

```
  hash1 = {"one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3}
  hash2 = hash1.reduce({}){ |h, (k,v)| h.merge(k => hash1) }
  hash3 = hash2.reduce({}){ |h, (k,v)| h.merge(k => hash2) }
  hash4 = hash3.reduce({}){ |h, (k,v)| h.merge(k => hash3) }
```

hash4 is a 'nested' hash i.e. a hash with string keys and similarly 'nested' hash values.

The 'symbolize_keys' method for Hash in Rails lets us easily convert the string keys to symbols. But I'm looking for an **elegant** way to convert all keys (primary keys plus keys of all hashes within hash4) to symbols.

The point is to save myself from my (*imo*) ugly solution:

```
  class Hash
    def symbolize_keys_and_hash_values
      symbolize_keys.reduce({}) do |h, (k,v)|
        new_val = v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.symbolize_keys_and_hash_values : v
        h.merge({k => new_val})
      end
    end
  end

  hash4.symbolize_keys_and_hash_values #=> desired result
```

FYI: Setup is Rails 3.2.17 and Ruby 2.1.1

Update:

Answer is `hash4.deep_symbolize_keys` for Rails <= 5.0

Answer is `JSON.parse(JSON[hash4], symbolize_names: true)` for Rails > 5

Comment: you can look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys

Comment: @jvnill - write it as an answer...

Comment: @SyedHumzaShah, however, be aware that you having to "deep symbolize" betrays your lack of knowledge of what actually is in your hash. Avoid the method and use your knowledge of how your data structure is built. If it is so totally dynamic that you do need deep symbolize, you might consider using a tree object instead, with its traversal methods and other assets pertinent to trees.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky if your hash has not been generated by you, e.g. a config file you're loading in, then it's common to not know what's actually in the hash...

Answer (score 136, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this

1. There's a [`deep_symbolize_keys` method in Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys)

   `hash.deep_symbolize_keys!`
2. As mentioned by @chrisgeeq, there is a [`deep_transform_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_transform_keys) method that's available from Rails 4.

   `hash.deep_transform_keys(&:to_sym)`

   There is also a bang `!` version to replace the existing object.
3. There is another method called [`with_indifferent_access`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html).  This allows you to access a hash with either a string or a symbol like how `params` are in the controller.  This method doesn't have a bang counterpart.

   `hash = hash.with_indifferent_access`
4. The last one is using `JSON.parse`.  I personally don't like this because you're doing 2 transformations - hash to json then json to hash.

   `JSON.parse(JSON[h], symbolize_names: true)`

UPDATE:

16/01/19 - add more options and note deprecation of deep_symbolize_keys

19/04/12 - remove deprecated note.  only the implementation used in the method is deprecated, not the method itself.

Comment: This method is deprecated in rails >= 5.1,transform_keys is used instead [see this](https://github.com/netguru/messenger-ruby/pull/29)

Comment: [deep_symbolize_keys](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys) method is not deprecated at all. @chrisgeeq's comment points to a commit that uses `transform_keys` instead of deprecated `symbolize_keys` method. Please edit this answer to correct this.

Answer (score 28):

You cannot use this method for params or any other instance of `ActionController::Parameters` any more, because `deep_symbolize_keys` method is deprecated in Rails 5.0+ due to security reasons and will be removed in Rails 5.1+ as `ActionController::Parameters` no longer
inherits from Hash

So this approach by @Uri Agassi **seems to be the universal** one.

```
JSON.parse(JSON[h], symbolize_names: true)
```

---

However, Rails Hash object still does have it.

So options are:

- if you don't use Rails or just don't care:

  ```
  JSON.parse(JSON[h], symbolize_names: true)
  ```
- with Rails and ActionController::Parameters:

  ```
  params.to_unsafe_h.deep_symbolize_keys
  ```
- with Rails and plain Hash

  ```
  h.deep_symbolize_keys
  ```

Comment: Any information for its deprecation? There is no notice of deprecation on [its documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0.1/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys), and I am using it without encountering any deprecation warnings.

Comment: @FranklinYu I have edited answer adding some details.

Comment: It's deprecated on `ActionController::Parameters` (as implied in [this issue](https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_import/issues/91)), but not on `Hash` as I said above. As your quote says, *`ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from hash*. This question is about `Hash`.

Comment: Rails is in 6.1 and it's still not deprecated... It's an excellent answer, but I can't upvote it because it is misleading in this small issue.

Answer (score 6):

In rails you can create HashWithIndifferentAccess class. Create an instance of this class passing your hash to its constructor and then access it with keys that are symbols or strings (like params of Controller's Actions):

```
hash = {'a' => {'b' => [{c: 3}]}}

hash = hash.with_indifferent_access
# equal to:
# hash = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(hash)

hash[:a][:b][0][:c]

=> 3
```

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest something like this:

```
class Object
  def deep_symbolize_keys
    self
  end
end

class Hash
  def deep_symbolize_keys
    symbolize_keys.tap { |h| h.each { |k, v| h[k] = v.deep_symbolize_keys } }
  end
end

{'a'=>1, 'b'=>{'c'=>{'d'=>'d'}, e:'f'}, 'g'=>1.0, 'h'=>nil}.deep_symbolize_keys
# => {:a=>1, :b=>{:c=>{:d=>"d"}, :e=>"f"}, :g=>1.0, :h=>nil}
```

You can also easily extend it to support `Arrays`:

```
class Array
  def deep_symbolize_keys
    map(&:deep_symbolize_keys)
  end
end

{'a'=>1, 'b'=>[{'c'=>{'d'=>'d'}}, {e:'f'}]}.deep_symbolize_keys
# => {:a=>1, :b=>[{:c=>{:d=>"d"}}, {:e=>"f"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Uri. Apparently, there's a built-in 'deep_symbolize_keys' method that ships with Rails. I had gone through the Ruby docs but, stupidly, not through the Rails API docs. jvnill (above) was able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: @SyedHumzaShah - LOL, I wasn't aware of that either. It does not support arrays though :P

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest:

```
JSON.parse(hash_value.to_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

- [Hash#to_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-to_s) to convert the hash to a string;
- [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regex to convert the keys from strings to representations of symbols; and then
- [Kernel#eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) to convert the string back into a hash.

This is an easy solution to your problem, but, you should only consider using it if you can trust that `eval` is not going to produce something nasty.  If you have control over the content of the hash being converted, that should not be a problem.

This approach could be used for other kinds of nested objects, such as ones containing both arrays and hashes.

**Code**

```
def symbolize_hash(h)
  eval(h.to_s.gsub(/\"(\w+)\"(?==>)/, ':\1'))
end
```

**Examples**

```
symbolize_hash(hash4)
  #=> {:one=>{:one=>  {:one=>  {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3},
  #                    :two=>  {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3},
  #                    :three=>{:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}},
  #           :two=>  {:one=>  {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3},
  #                    :two=>  {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3},
  #                    :three=>{:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}},
  #           :three=>{:one=>  {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3},
  #                    :two=>  {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3},
  #                    :three=>{:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}}},
  #    :two=>{:one=>  {:one=>  {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3},
  #    ...
  #    :three=>{:one=>{:one=>  {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3},
  #    ...
  #                    :three=>{:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3}}}}

symbolize_hash({'a'=>1, 'b'=>[{'c'=>{'d'=>'d'}}, {e:'f'}]})
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>[{:c=>{:d=>"d"}}, {:e=>"f"}]}
```

**Explanation**

`(?==>)` in the regex is a zero-width postive lookahead. `?=` signifies positive lookahead; `=>` is the string that must immediately follow the match to `\"(\w+)\"`. `\1` in `':\1'` (or I could have written `":\\1"`) is a string beginning with a colon followed by a backreference to the content of capture group #1, the key matching `\w+` (without the quotes).

Comment: If you are going to serialize and parse - don't you think the JSON would be more appropriate: `JSON.parse(JSON[h], symbolize_names: true)`?

Comment: You may be right, @Uri. I've been meaning to find time to see what JSON is all about.

Comment: This point here about JSON.parse having a "symbolize_names" option is a hidden gem - thank you.