# How to convert nested string hash to symbol hash using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

The server is using JSON API which returns a nested data structure. I have tried to parse it using `JSON.parse` but it is converted the json string to string hash by default.

**Sample Data**

```
{
  "data"=>
  {
    "id"=>"1",
    "type"=>"users",
    "attributes"=>
    {
      "email"=>"tia_heller@lebsack.info",
      "name"=>"Tanner Kreiger"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried code below but it only convert one level deep (not children hash)

```
  def json_body
    str_hash = JSON.parse(response.body)
    str_hash.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v; memo}
  end
```

I have also tried `symbolize_keys` from Rails which only convert the first level as well (see `:data` and the rest is the same),

```
{:data=>{"id"=>"1", "type"=>"users", "attributes"=>{"email"=>"darrion_hackett@weberharvey.io", "name"=>"Cleo Braun"}}}
```

What is the best approach to recursively convert the nested string hash into symbol hash?

**Desired Result**

All the value can be access using symbol, like `json_response[:data][:attributes]`.

Comment: there is [`deep_symbolize_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys) - exactly for these purposes ;)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, that's for `rails`. The question is for `ruby`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
JSON.parse(result, symbolize_keys: true)
```

More info http://apidock.com/ruby/JSON/parse

or on the hash itself

```
hash = { 'name' => 'Rob', 'age' => '28' }

hash.symbolize_keys
# => {:name=>"Rob", :age=>"28"}
```

http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/symbolize_keys

These don't seem to do it recursively though.

There's also `deep_symbolize_keys!` in Rails

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys

Comment: I have tried `symbolize_keys` which only symbolize the first level keys

Comment: @LiXinyang did you try giving `JSON.parse` the parameter to symbolize_keys?

Comment: Thanks, `deep_symolize_keys` does the work. wonder if there is a pure Ruby solution.

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927653/how-to-elegantly-symbolize-keys-for-a-nested-hash you can use the `symbolize_names` parameter on `JSON.parse` to do it, I guess that's pure Ruby if you include `json`?